# Use ViewBag object in JQuery, value does not display correctly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a MVC3 app. In my action, I have  ViewBag object that has either true or false value - I used breakpoint and can see that in the action, they have the correct values.
Now, when I get to the view, I want to check these  ViewBag object in jQuery
 Code:

```
if (@ViewBag.ind == true) {
        $objKpr = $(".@ViewBag.kpr");
        $objKpr.click();
    }
```

When I tested own code with Firebug, it  returned

```
 if (False == false) 
         {
        $objKpr = $(".@ViewBag.kpr");
        $objKpr.click();
         }
```

Viewbag was interpreted as a 'False' rather than a variable holding a value of false.Why is this happening?

Thanks for answers
But the question was in another-Why a ViewBag inside a jQuery would not yield the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
var condition = @(myBooleanVariableInCSharp ? "true" : "false";
if (condition == true) {
    $objKpr = $(".@ViewBag.kpr");
    $objKpr.click();
}
```

### OR

You should use `@ViewBag.ind.ToString().ToLower()`. You need to convert the value which JavaScript can understand.

Your problem as bool values are *lowercase* in javascript and *uppercase* in C#

Like

```
if (@ViewBag.ind.ToString().ToLower() == true) {
    $objKpr = $(".@ViewBag.kpr");
    $objKpr.click();
}
```

Comment: +1 can't see anything wrong with this answer, would also love to know why someone downvoted it?

Comment: Satpal.Why is @ViewBag.ind.ToString().ToLower()?why not just use ViewBag.ind.ToLower()?

Comment: This solution may cause errors if `@ViewBag.ind` is null. BTW, i'm not the downvoter.

Comment: @Denis `@ViewBag.ind` is assumed to be of type `bool`, so the `ToLower()` method isn't available on it without turning it into a `string` first.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `@ViewBag.MyProperty` in your code will cause the Razor engine to render the property by calling `ToString()` on the value.  E.g.

```
if (@ViewBag.ind == true) {
```

Renders as:

```
if (True == true) {
```

So you may want to change your code to something like:

```
if (@ViewBag.ind.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() === true)
```

Although the values in `ViewBag` are only available to inject into the JavaScript/View when the page is rendered.  They're not as dynamic as JavaScript, where the variables are held client side and can be flipped/changed as many times as you like.

You may wish to use the technique to inject initial values for your scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ind = @ViewBag.ind.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();

    DoSomething(ind);
});

function DoSomething(ind) {
    if (ind) {
        $objKpr = $(".@ViewBag.kpr");
        $objKpr.click();
    }
}
```

This way you can initialise the behaviour of `ind` at render, but then change the value of `ind` on the client side and call the function `DoSomething()` many times with different values.

You may wish to look into using JSON, AJAX calls and the JavaScript Module pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
if ("@(ViewBag.ind == null ? "false" : ViewBag.ind.ToString().ToLower())" === "true") {
```

It will not give errors even if `ViewBag.ind` is null.

Thanks!